# Holoviews with xarray dataset: How to scatter-plot two variables?

Tags: python, plot, python-xarray, holoviews

I got the following xarray xr.Dataset:

```
# st_data
Dimensions:       (observations: 3429703)
Coordinates:
  * observations  (observations) MultiIndex
  - a             (observations) object 'XMD1' 'XMD1' ... 'ZZPU'
  - b             (observations) object '00000049541' ... '00000232254'
Data variables:
    counts        (observations) int32 dask.array<chunksize=(151311,), meta=np.ndarray>
    true          (observations) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(151311,), meta=np.ndarray>
    predicted     (observations) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(95325,), meta=np.ndarray>
```

Now I'd like to do a scatter plot of `true` vs. `predicted:

`hv.Scatter(data=hv.Dataset(st_data), kdims=["observations"], vdims=["true", "predicted"])`

I assume this is wrong, because it fails with `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'item'`.
What do I have to change to get a working scatter plot here?

Answer (score 0):

Normally for a scatterplot in Holoviews:

kdims is the value on your x-axis, and
vdims is the value on your y-axis.

I don't know much about xarray, since I always use pandas df, but does this work?

```
hv.Scatter(data=st_data, kdims=['true'], vdims=['predicted'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a DataFrame from my Xarray Dataset and use that to plot the scatter like so:

```
dataframe = xr_dataset.data.to_dataframe()

scatter = hv.Scatter(dataframe, 'variable1', 'variable2')
```